# How to refresh/reload partial view from inside main view in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am displaying a partial view (shopping cart) inside my main (pricing view) view using RenderAction

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Cart", "ShoppingCart"); %>
```

As user adds items to cart on the main view I have to update the partial view to display newely added items. Here is the code for my partail view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Trl.ViewModels.Cart>" %>
<% foreach (var _hotel in Model.Hotels)
   { %>
   Hotel Name: <%: _hotel.Name %> <br/>
   Price: <%: _hotel.TotalPrice %>
<% } %>
```

"Trl.ViewModels.Cart" object used in above user control will contain newely added items as I am using ASP.NET Session State to persist Cart. How to refresh/reload this partial view from my main view so it can display newely added items?

Comment: alex, do you mean 'refresh' as in re-render the partial whenever a new item is added via some other means - i.e. is the cart sitting on a sidebar somewhere and the 'action' is taking place in the main content area and thus you want to update the sidebar cart if an item is added in the main section? sorry for stating the bleedin obvious, but just want to clarify

Comment: Jim, thats exactly the scenario. The cart is on the right hand side of main page inside a column and DIV.

Comment: alex - have added a brief summary answer as to how it might be possible, gorra head...

Comment: changed the tags to -mvc as question isn't mvc2 specific and might get a better response on general -mvc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ok, i've got a clear(er) idea of whats required.

I'm assuming that the main content area is updated via ajax. If this is the case, then my approach would be to make the update via ajax and in the controller action, return partialview that contains the sidebar cart. For this to work, you'd need a named id for the div that contained the cart in order to target that as an update site.

without further ado, a quick code demo of what i mean:

controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Cart item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // or could be added to session["cart"] etc..
        _repository.Add(item);
        var cartItems = _repository.Find(x => x.cartID = item.cartID);
        return PartialView("CartMini", cartItems);
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

main view (in your right hand column - this would be where your partial view was originally defined):

```
<div id="miniCart"></div>
```

in another part of the page (semi psuedo-code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function updateCart() {
         var tdata = $(frm).serialize(); 
         // or your data in the format that will be used ??
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: tdata,
           url : '<%= Url.Action("Create", "Cart") %>',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) { success(result); }  
        });
      }); 

    function success(result){
        $("#miniCart").html(result);
    }
</script>
```

and that really is the bare bones of what's needed. sorry for the rush on this, had started a while ago and phone went, now have to head off :). will add further if not clear later.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I got it working partially. The issue I am having is, my shopping cart is inside a DIV but its an .ascx control and being rendered using "Html.RenderAction" like this: <div id="rightColumn"><% Html.RenderAction("Cart", "ShoppingCart"); %></div> - .ascx control uses a strongly typed view model to populate the shopping cart. Ideally, I need a way by which I can re-render the ascx control. I tried $("#rightColumn").load("/ShoppingCart/Cart"); to re-load the DIV/ascx but for some reason its re-loading only once - does not re-load if I add 2 items to cart.

Comment: Jim - Pls. discard my comments above. I had made a mistake - its working fine. Thank you much for your suggestion/solution.

Comment: @Jim you are my saver as well, +1 from me :)

Comment: davide - glad to have been of assistance. i love the fact that SO still finds solutions for folk without prejudice to 'time' :). all the best from me!!

Comment: Just a thought, maybe change data type to html otherwise it might throw a parse exception when returning the html from the partial view

Comment: good point andy - been a while since working on mvc stuff, so i'm sure current versions may also work differently too. cheers